# How to Create ACLs in Spring-Security-Acl

Tags: grails, spring-security, acl

I'm just getting started with Grails and am hitting a wall trying to configure the spring-security-acl plugin. I've been following the [official plugin tutorial](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/guide/single.html#3.%20Tutorial) but am unable to get past the Bootstrapping phase when trying to run my app (using a `Position` domain class rather than a `Report` class. Most of my problems have surrounded the ACL portion of the app.

The issue I'm unable to get past is in the `grantPermissions()` function of `Bootstrap.groovy`. Per the tutorial's instructions, by functions starts off like this:

```
private void grantPermissions() {
    def positions = []
    100.times {
        long id = it + 1
        def position = new Position(title: "position$id").save()
        positions << position
        aclService.createAcl(
                objectIdentityRetrievalStrategy.getObjectIdentity(position))
    }
```

IntelliJ is warning me on the `aclService.createAcl` line that it "Cannot infer argument types. This inspection reports assignments with incompatible types." Indeed if I try to run the app anyways, it crashes on that line with the error:

```
| Error 2013-03-09 09:35:24,207 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
Message: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
    Line | Method
->>   68 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_grantPermissions_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | grantPermissions                 in BootStrap
|     29 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Appendix**

In case it matters, my `Position` domain object looks like this:

```
class Position {

    String title
    Boolean draft

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I don't think this issue would be related, but it was an ACL-related deviation from the tutorial, so for posterity's sake... The first issue I had which (I think) I've solved was in PositionService.groovy, I was getting errors in IntelliJ on the code chunk:

```
def acl = aclUtilService.readAcl(position)

// Remove all permissions associated with this particular
// recipient (string equality to KISS)
acl.entries.eachWithIndex { entry, i ->
    if (entry.sid.equals(position) &&
            entry.permission.equals(permission)) {
        acl.deleteAce i
    }
}
```

It looked like the issue was not being able to find the function `deleteAce` on the generic `acl` object; I was able to solve this by specifying the type `MutableAcl` as in

```
MutableAcl acl = aclUtilService.readAcl(position)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All properties have an implicit `nullable:false` constraint, but you're only setting the `title` property. `draft` isn't set, so validation is failing and all of your `Position`s are null.

This should work:

```
def position = new Position(title: "position$id", draft: false).save()
```

Comment: You make it look so easy... Thanks a million!